# Perl JSON::RPC::Client Not a HASH reference Error

Tags: perl, ssl

When i call remote **echo** procedure my call reachs to rpc server which is written in python with txjsonrpc module. but this script says:

> malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "read failed:  at /us...") at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Moose/Meta/Method/Delegation.pm line 110

Any idea? Code is here:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON::RPC::LWP;
use Net::SSL ();
use JSON::RPC::Client;

$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;
# CA cert peer verification
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_FILE}   = 'ca_file';
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_DIR}    = 'ca_dir';

# Client PKCS12 cert support
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE}     = 'pkcs12 cert';
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD} = 'password';

my $ua = eval { LWP::UserAgent->new() }
        or die "Could not make user-agent! $@";
$ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostname => 0);

print "JSON RPC CONNECTION\n";
my $rpc = JSON::RPC::Client->new(
  ua => $ua,
  version => '2.0'
);
my $result = $rpc->call( 'https://...', {method=>'echo', params=>['param']});
print $result->result, "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of JSON::RPC::Client are you using?  If it is the most current one, that error is happening because the server is returning something other than a JSON object.

Comment: I use latest version of JSON::RPC::Client. It works with JSON::RPC::LWP instead of JSON::RPC::Client. What is the difference?

Comment: I don't know.  Possibly a bug in JSON::RPC::Client - I see at least one (harmless) one in the code.  You could add `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $obj->content;` just before line 193 in Client.pm ( `$content->{error} ? ...` ) and see what it is getting.